# Algebraic numbers proof

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was just wondering if anyone knew how one would prove that every $k$-th root of a rational number $r$ is algebraic? My thought would be that some $r$ is equal to $\frac{p}{q}$ but since you are taking the $n$-th root $p$ and $q$ aren't necessarily integers anymore which is a requirement for algebraic- integer coefficients.

Comment: It is an algebraic number for sure but not necessarily an algebraic integer

Comment: Uh,  how would you prove ever even number is an integer?  K-th root of a rational number solves the polynomial $x^k=r $ so it is algebraic by definition.

Comment: Okay, if you have the definition of *integer* coefficient (which is *NOT* nescessary ) then you have $nx^k=m $ where $r=m/n $.  Integer coefficients are *not* nescessary as if you have rational coefficients you just multiply both sides by a common denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is a rational number, then $r=\frac{p}{q}$ for integers $p,q$. Then a $k$th root of $r$ is a root of the polynomial $f(X)=qX^k-p$, which has integer coefficients.

Comment: This proves it is an algebraic number not an algebraic integer for which we need to display a monic polynomial

Comment: @marwalix: It looks to me like the question says to show it is an algebraic number. Naturally it won't be an algebraic integer in general.

Comment: It seems to me as well but I am confused with the requirement for integer coefficients

Comment: You can either define algebraic numbers as roots of monic polynomials with rational coefficients, or (by clearing denominators) as roots of (not necessarily monic) polynomials with integer coefficients.